# VideoJS and Blackberry10 Full Screen Mode

Tags: html, fullscreen, blackberry-10, video.js

HTML5 full-screen overlay is behind content text.

It appears that any content *after* the video is displayed, renders above the video on full-screen.

[image: Example]

The blackberry developer tools were no help when trying to find the issue, or change z-indexes on various elements.

Is there a hook for html5 in blackberry that I can get to display above the content?
Is this a Blackberry bug or a VideoJS bug?

Comment: Not 100% sure what is causing this, but I got around the issue by taking the video out of the main content and putting it into a modal.  That way, the element wasn't a child of the content area and it displayed above the site.  I'm still interested in an inline solution.

Comment: Same problem here. I had to hide any elements around the video to get around it. Seems like a BB10 problem

Comment: What version of BB10 OS are you seeing this on? Do you also see  this on the videojs.com front-page?